# How do you list all functions and aliases in a specific script?

Tags: bash, function

I have a Bash script that's getting quite long.  It would be nice if I could list all the functions in it.  Even better would be listing the name of the function and any documentation about its usage, eg parameters.

Comment: Would running it and then getting a log of all calls also be an option?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In general, it's impossible to list all functions without executing the script, because a function could be declared by something like `eval $(/some/program)`. But if the functions are declared “normally”, you can search for things that look like function definitions.

```
grep -E '^[[:space:]]*([[:alnum:]_]+[[:space:]]*\(\)|function[[:space:]]+[[:alnum:]_]+)' myscript
```

There's no function typing or documentation facility in shell scripts, so any documentation would have to come from comments. Here's a crude Perl snippet that extracts commonly-formatted function definitions as well as immediately preceding or succeeding comments.

```
perl -0777 -ne '
    while (/^((?:[ \t]*\#.*\n)*)               # preceding comments
             [ \t]*(?:(\w+)[ \t]*\(\)|         # foo ()
                      function[ \t]+(\w+).*)   # function foo
             ((?:\n[ \t]+\#.*)*)               # following comments
           /mgx) {
        $name = "$2$3";
        $comments = "$1$4";
        $comments =~ s/^[ \t]*#+/#/mg;
        chomp($comments);
        print "$name\n$comments\n";
    }' myscript
```

A more precise way to print function names, if you can run the script without causing any side effects, or if you can isolate all function definitions in a subscript, is to run the script and then make bash print out all the function definitions. Unlike the text search method above, this includes weirdly-formatted function definitions and excludes false positives (e.g. in here documents), but this cannot find comments.

```
bash -c '. myscript; typeset -f'
```

Comment: `alias scriptinfo="grep -E '^[[:space:]]*([[:alnum:]_]+[[:space:]]*\(\)|function[[:space:]]+[[:alnum:]_]+)'"`    is now in my .profile.  Great tip Gilles. Thank you,

Comment: works also: `grep -E '^[[:space:]]*([[:alnum:]_]+[[:space:]]*\(\)|alias[[:space:]]+[[:alnum:]_]+)' myscript`

Answer (score 19):

The usual way is to use `declare -f` which will print a very long list of functions in an interactive bash shell. But inside an script, as most external functions are not defined, the list will be short and useful.

So:

```
declare -f
```

Will list functions (and definitions). And:

```
declare -F
```

will print a list of name functions only.

There is a (not so easy to use) option of `extdebug` which if set, the line numbers of the definition of each function will also be printed by `declare -F`. But `extdebug` needs to be set at script loading time (as all lines need to be known to be able to list them).

Comment: `extdebug` does not need to be set at load time. You can just `shopt -s extdebug; declare -F the_func; shopt -u extdebug` and it works perfectly.

Comment: It ‘‘goes without saying’’ — and yet, perhaps should be stated explicitly — that you would edit your script (or a copy thereof) and insert ```declare -F; exit``` after all the functions are defined, but before any main-line code, and then run it.

Answer (score 4):

```
declare -F | awk '{print $NF}' | sort | egrep -v "^_"
```

Comment: Worked perfect for adding into my script for a loop through all the function names where multiple input will be allowed into all functions.  Shortened my code of my script by almost 1K. Best answer here!  Thank you!  +1

Comment: (1) In pipelines, it’s more efficient to reduce the amount of data flowing through the pipes by putting the filters that decrease the amount of data earlier and putting the filters that increase the amount of data later.  So it would be better to do `… | egrep -v "^_" | sort`.  (2) You’re underutilizing `awk`.  You can do `awk '$NF !~ /^_/ {print $NF}'` and eliminate the `grep`.  (3) It seems to me that the output from `declare -F` is already sorted, so you don’t need `sort`.